How to expand items.data.price.product in a stripe subscription
Given the API documentation about the Subscription object I should be able to use
stripe subscriptions list --customer cus_QgBmuycCay7CGu --expand data.items.data.price.product

However, I get this error:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "You cannot expand more than 4 levels of a property. Property: data.items.data.price.product",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_OkWSMMvr4CH5i1?t=1723990163",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}


It seems that you can't handle multiple layers in stripe so you can't chain different objects which >= 4 as shown from your query
data.items.data.price.product
You can do this first
stripe subscriptions list --customer cus_QgBmuycCay7CGu --expand data.items.data.price

Then run this command after:
stripe prices retrieve price_ID --expand product
You can go further to create a customized function
import stripe

# Set your secret key
stripe.api_key = "your_secret_key"

# First, get the subscriptions with expanded prices
subscriptions = stripe.Subscription.list(
    customer="cus_QgBmuycCay7CGu",
    expand=["data.items.data.price"]
)

def get_products(subscriptions):
   # Now, get the product details for each price
   for sublist in subscriptions.data:
       for item in sublist.items.data:
          price_id = item.price.id
          price = stripe.Price.retrieve(price_id, expand=["product"])
       print(price.product)


I see - so I won't be able to get it directly. Thank you.

@mp3por apparently not, I am glad I could help :)
